# Возникает ошибка java: 'else' without 'if'

Tags: java, android

```
  int testScore = 95;
    if (testScore > 90) ;
    System.out.println("отлично");

    { else
        System.out.println("хорошо");


    }
}
```

}

Comment: У вас в коде конструкция if заканчивается на первой же точке с запятой. А дальше else уже висит сам по себе без if.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой синтаксис этого оператора:

```
if (testScore > 90) {
    System.out.println("отлично");
} else {
    System.out.println("хорошо");
}
```

Если оператор выполнения условия один, то фигурные скобки можно не ставить